# Need help developing an algorithm/formula to compare raw data from gyroscope/accelerometer to predefined values and put into a mobile app

Tags: database, algorithm, architecture, data-science, sensors

I am using the sensors (gyroscope/accelerometer) of smartphones to acquire raw X, Y, X values with time stamps via a sensordemo created.  I would like to be able to compare these data points to predefined values.

For example, if a user (female) is standing on one leg for 30 seconds, if she looses her balance at 14 seconds then she is at risk for falling. If she first looses her balance at 19 seconds then she is not at risk for falling.

I need help writing a formula to be able to compare the raw data to predefined model in to a mobile application.

Comment: Why do you need help? What was the problem when you tried to do this yourself? Currently it is not clear which specific programming problem you are asking about.

Comment: ` to compare these data points to predefined values. ` .. why just putting 3D `data` & 3D `predefined values` side-by-side is insufficient? | btw, [edit] to add what u tried.. & maybe.. a search in [android.se] would help